# read xml with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get

```
<dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI" >bitstream link</dc:identifier>
```

and dc:title,publisher etc using C# in my MVC app need help as i am new to xml

```
<metadata>
  <uketd_dc:uketddc
         xmlns:uketd_dc="http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/"
         xmlns:doc="http://www.lyncode.com/xoai"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:uketdterms="http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/terms/" 
         xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/ http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/uketd_dc.xsd">
    <dc:date>2010-10-14T17:31:59Z</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2010-10-14T17:31:59Z</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2003-01-01</dc:date>
    <dc:date>2015-06-12T10:34:09Z</dc:date>
    <dcterms:issued>2003-01-01</dcterms:issued>
    <dcterms:isReferencedBy xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://www.iadb.org/en/publications/publication-detail,7101.html?id=4486</dcterms:isReferencedBy>
    <dcterms:abstract>This book looks at the key issues and lessons that policymakers must consider in designing an adequate framework for dealing with financial crises. These include structural problems and their causes, policy actions, the role of market discipline, and preemptive strategies.</dcterms:abstract>
    <dc:title>Financial Crises in Japan and Latin America</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>Zahler, Roberto</dc:creator>
    <dc:contributor>VICTORCO</dc:contributor>
    <dc:subject>Financial Crises &amp; Economic Stabilization</dc:subject>
    <dc:description>This book looks at the key issues and lessons that policymakers must consider in designing an adequate framework for dealing with financial crises. These include structural problems and their causes, policy actions, the role of market discipline, and preemptive strategies.</dc:description>
    <dc:type>Books</dc:type>
    <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>9781931003476</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier>http://www.iadb.org/en/publications/publication-detail,7101.html?id=4486</dc:identifier>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:publisher>Inter-American Development Bank (IDB)</dc:publisher>
    <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf?sequence=1</dc:identifier>
    <uketdterms:checksum xsi:type="uketdterms:MD5">83c42636d27d253499be4db09db02312</uketdterms:checksum>
    <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf.png?sequence=11</dc:identifier>
    <uketdterms:checksum xsi:type="uketdterms:MD5">4d4c1c29a730054db0cfcfc477333626</uketdterms:checksum>
    <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf.jpg?sequence=5</dc:identifier>
    <uketdterms:checksum xsi:type="uketdterms:MD5">7e49ce2e1c21c12e141aa50402037b25</uketdterms:checksum>
    <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf.txt?sequence=10</dc:identifier>
    <uketdterms:checksum xsi:type="uketdterms:MD5">bad0c21c28fc8a9946bdfa5eae2bf59d</uketdterms:checksum>
  </uketd_dc:uketddc>
</metadata>
```

I tried the below code and not able to get the details

```
XDocument billingData = XDocument.Load("http://publications.iadb.org/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=uketd_dc");
XNamespace oai_dc = XNamespace.Get("http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/");
XNamespace oai_dc1 = XNamespace.Get("http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/ http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/uketd_dc.xsd");
XNamespace dc = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/");

var billings = from billing in billingData.Descendants(oai_dc + "uketd_dc").Descendants(oai_dc1 + "dc")
               select new Billing(billing.Element(dc + "title").Value, billing.Element(dc + "creator").Value,
                       billing.Element(dc + "description").Value, billing.Element(dc + "identifier").Value);
allBillings.AddRange(billings.ToList<Billing>());
```

I don't know whether i am doing correct.

Comment: I have posted the code which i tried on top..please check

Comment: "*and not able to get the details*" Why? You get an error? Wrong result? Which exactly?  By the way, that would help us to help you if you posted clear and well indented code.

Comment: From the above given xml i am trying to get the title, contributor, publisher and identifier which contains the .pdf link..On the trying the above code it shows enumeration yielded no results. how can i get these things from the above xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is looking for descendants with the element local names of `uketd_dc` and then `dc`.  You don't have any elements with those names - these seem to be namespace prefixes.  Also, I'm not sure what your `oai_dc1` namespace is supposed to be.

What you probably want is this:

```
XNamespace uketd_dc = "http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/ethos-oai/2.0/";
XNamespace dc = "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/";

var billings = from e in doc.Descendants(uketd_dc + "uketddc")
               select new Billing(
                    (string)e.Element(dc + "title"),
                    (string)e.Element(dc + "creator"),
                    (string)e.Element(dc + "description"),
                    (string)e.Element(dc + "identifier")
                    );
```

Note that your XML has multiple elements for some of these (e.g. identifier).  This will return the first one.

Comment: One more doubt actually i am getting the xml from a OAI-PMH it actually consists of 1000 records but i am only getting 100 records   from the code below                                                                   XDocument billingData2 = XDocument.Load("http://repository.iadb.org/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=oai_dc");    Can i get all records in one request.

Comment: It will get all of them.  If it's only returning 100, then there are only 100 in the source.  I would point out that there are 100 in the XML returned by the link in your question.  The link in your comment is different and returns different XML with different namespaces - there are only 87 records in that.

Comment: XDocument billingData = XDocument.Load("http://publications.iadb.org/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=uketd_dc");                                      In the end of xml it shows something like this <resumptionToken completeListSize="6305" cursor="0">MToxMDB8Mjp8Mzp8NDp8NTp1a2V0ZF9kYw==</resumptionToken>                                                                             But on accessing link directly it shows total of 6306 records...

Comment: As above xml has multiple elements for some of these (e.g. identifier).How to retrieve the identifier which has a link to pdf and png                   <dc:identifier>International Lending and Debt Problems</dc:identifier><dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf?sequence=1</dc:identifier>
    <dc:identifier xsi:type="dcterms:URI">http://publications.iadb.org/bitstream/handle/11319/195/Financial+Crises+in+Japan+and+Latin+America.pdf.png?sequence=11</dc:identifier>

Comment: You'd have to find some way of identifying those and filter the identifer elements using `Where`.  I can't see how you can tell if it's png or pdf based on the uri.

Comment: XDocument billingData = XDocument.Load("publications.iadb.org/oai/…); The above code returns only 100 records. In the end of xml it shows something like this <resumptionToken completeListSize="6305" cursor="0">MToxMDB8Mjp8Mzp8NDp8NTp1a2V0ZF9kYw==</resumptionToken> .But on accessing link directly it shows total of 6306 records... How to acces the full records

Comment: Ask the people who provide the API?